# Assigning factor labels and levels to several variables in a loop in R

Tags: r, loops, type-conversion

I have data from a survey with a Likert scale and I need to convert a subset of variables that have character responses (less, same, more, not applicable) to factors with specific values (-1, 0, 1, NA). What I've tried:

```
q<-select(df,starts_with("A"))

for(x in q){
  x<-factor(x,
            levels=c("Less","Same","More"),
            labels=c(-1,0,1),
            exclude=c("Not Applicable"))
  }
```

The select function part works. The assignment does not. From putting a print(summary(x)) command inside the loop after the factor() call, it seems like x is being assigned the factor() value, and neither the content of q or df is changed at the end of the process. What do I do?

Comment: `df%>%mutate(across(starts_with('A'), ~factor(.x, levels=c("Less","Same","More"), labels=c(-1,0,1), exclude=c("Not Applicable"))))`

Comment: That's also not working for not some reason, but thank you for pointing me to the across() function. The factor() call works alone, but for some reason using across() also leaves everything as characters.

Comment: that is because you have not assigned back to the dataframe. ie `df <- df %>%mutate....` then check the `df` again

Comment: Yep, that did it. Thanks! I'm totally new to R.

Answer (score 0):

Usually `lapply` is used to apply a function on (selected) columns of a data frame (data frames are actually lists thus `l-apply`).

Consider this example

```
dat
#           X             A1             A2   A3
# 1 0.9148060           Same           More Same
# 2 0.9370754           Same Not Applicable Same
# 3 0.2861395           Less           Less More
# 4 0.8304476 Not Applicable           Less More
# 5 0.6417455           More           Same Less
# 6 0.5190959 Not Applicable Not Applicable Less

## find columns
q <- startsWith(names(dat), 'A')

## lapply the factor function with its arguments on columns subset
dat[q] <- lapply(dat[q], factor, 
                 levels=c("Less", "Same", "More"), 
                 labels=c(-1, 0, 1),
                 exclude=c("Not Applicable")
)

dat
#           X   A1   A2 A3
# 1 0.9148060    0    1  0
# 2 0.9370754    0 <NA>  0
# 3 0.2861395   -1   -1  1
# 4 0.8304476 <NA>   -1  1
# 5 0.6417455    1    0 -1
# 6 0.5190959 <NA> <NA> -1
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(X = c(0.914806043496355, 0.937075413297862, 0.286139534786344, 
0.830447626067325, 0.641745518893003, 0.519095949130133), A1 = c("Same", 
"Same", "Less", "Not Applicable", "More", "Not Applicable"), 
    A2 = c("More", "Not Applicable", "Less", "Less", "Same", 
    "Not Applicable"), A3 = c("Same", "Same", "More", "More", 
    "Less", "Less")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```